# Layout Automate map scale

Tags: scale, layouts

the following code automates the project CRS for display as text in my maps.

[% @project_crs %]

Can anyone provide me with something which will automate the scale of the map?

Comment: If you provide us with the software you're working with, we might be able.

Comment: I made an answer assuming you are using QGIS. @crustygaz , let me know if it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access to the scale of your map that is in the same layout.

To do so there is a function called `item_variable()` that could access to all the variables for any item in your layout.

Take the name of your map in your layout. In my case it is `Carte 1`

[image]

Then add a text box with the expression below to get the format you prefer. Don't forget to change the text `Carte 1` to the name of your map.

To get a format like "18836.438"

```
[%map_get( item_variables( 'Carte 1' ), 'map_scale' )%]
```

to get a "rounded" value like "19000"

```
[%round(map_get( item_variables( 'Carte 1' ), 'map_scale' ), -3)%]
```

to get a value like "1 : 18 836"

```
'1 : ' || format_number(map_get( item_variables( 'Carte 1' ), 'map_scale' ),0)
```